# HTML 5 homing missile

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, game-physics

This is my class

```
function Missile(drawX, drawY) {
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.width = 16;
    this.r = this.width * 0.5;
    this.height = 10;
    this.drawX = drawX;
    this.drawY = drawY;
    this.img = planeHomingMissile;
    this.rotation = -90;
}

Missile.prototype.draw = function () {
    ctxHM.save();
    ctxHM.translate(this.drawX, this.drawY);
    ctxHM.rotate(this.rotation); 
    ctxHM.drawImage(this.img, -this.r, -this.r);
    ctxHM.restore();
}
```

And this is my JavaScript logic:

```
function shootHomingMissile() {
    //if(!missileOut) {
        hMissile = new Missile(player1.drawX + 22, player1.drawY + 32);
        missileOut = true;
    //}
}

function updateHomingMissile() {
    if(missileOut) {
        var targetX = 500 - hMissile.drawX;
        var targetY = 50 - hMissile.drawY;
        //The atan2() method returns the arctangent of the quotient of its arguments, as a numeric value between PI and -PI radians.
        //The number returned represents the counterclockwise angle in radians (not degrees) between the positive X axis and the point (x, y)
        var rotations = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX) * 180 / Math.PI;
        hMissile.rotation = rotations;

        var vx = bulletSpd * (90 - Math.abs(rotations)) / 90;
        var vy;
        if (rotations < 0)
            vy = -bulletSpd + Math.abs(vx);
        else
            vy = bulletSpd - Math.abs(vx);

        hMissile.drawX += vx;   
        hMissile.drawY += vy;   
    }
}

function drawHomingMissile() {
    ctxHM.clearRect(0,0,575,800);   

    hMissile.draw();
}
```

I want my missile(facing upwards) to target (500, 50) and face it while targeting.

the movement seems to work but its not facing the target its just keeps rotating but the missile is going to the target.

I'm a starting developer so my code is kind of mess, please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your angle from radians to degrees and is using that for your `rotation()` which require radians.

Try this in your `Missile.prototype.draw`:

```
ctxHM.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
```

(or simply keep the angle in radians at all stages)

Comment: by "angles", did you mean "degrees"?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not even done with the grace period before people start commenting (or editing) :)

Comment: hmmm now its just looking up, i think in the rotations var, it did was already in radians.

Comment: @user3258965 `var rotations = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX); // * 180 / Math.PI;`

Comment: so i did that var rotations = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX) and ctxHM.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180);

try this:
press c in player 1
http://wyncoding.t15.org/kill/index.html

Comment: @Ken Thanks for leading me the right way. I kind of fixed it by doing this:

var rotations = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX);

and in the draw():

ctxHM.rotate(this.rotation + (Math.PI / 2));